# Is there a way to see how many of my answers are the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Out of idle curiosity, is there a way for me to see how many of my answers are also the 
accepted answer?

Comment: This has been answered on MSE some time ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59968/ratio-of-accepted-own-answers.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Drop your UserId into this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/949/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate

Comment: This might not be viewed as a constructive comment, but I just have to say that's really cool!

Comment: Just a note for others who may be confused as I was: If your username is "user1118321," for example, your userID is just the 1118321 part.

Comment: @user1118321 Expanding on that, if your username isn't of that form, go to your profile and look at the URL. It'll be of the form http://<stackexchange site>/users/<user id>/<username> (Of course, this works if your username *was* of that form too)

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, what is SO's average accepted answer rate?  With 84 answers, I have an acceptance rate of 38%.  Is that good, bad, or average?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson: You'd realistically want to limit that to some minimum number of answers. Otherwise, people who have a single answer that is accepted will bust the curve.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson, [that's average](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202651/accepted-answer-rate-for-users-3000-rep), though I'm curious to see what it is when you discard answers to questions with no accepted answer (mine's closer to 34% but I know I've provided several correct answers where the asker never showed back up).

Comment: A rate of 47% over 457 answers, sounds good ! @Jason I wonder why this average grows up to 50% when we take in account users with rep > 1k, and reach 63% (!!) without any rep restriction.

Comment: Interesting numbers, and valid point on including the people with only a few answers.  Good to know I'm running near the average!

Comment: @Jason Ow... I was just misediting the request. We stay around 37% with 1k+ rep users, and fall to 33% with 0+ rep user

Comment: Is this only for StackOverflow or across the whole of StackExchange?

Comment: @starsplusplus The SQL query only fetches data from one specific site, which you can set in the second input box.

Comment: @ComFreek Completely missed that second box. Thanks!

Comment: Given [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113652/1060656), could it be said that the "effective" average is `usr avg/SO avg`?

Answer (score 60):

Searching for

```
user:me is:answer
```

will give you the total number of answers you have.

Searching for

```
user:me isaccepted:yes
```

will give you the total number of answers you have that have been accepted.

Many more search goodies at https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: +1 Very nice.  Didn't know about `user:me` - that's cool.

Comment: This works for other stack exchange sites as well ! This should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 7):

In response to Matthew Johnson's comment on Henk Holterman's answer.

I created this query a while back which will show your accepted rate as well as all other users, so you can see how you're doing.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173121/users-with-accepted-answer-rate

It's slightly different to Henk Holterman's because it doesn't include questions which have no accepted answer.

Comment: Is the query really working? Otherwise kudos to the guy who answered 1,295 times and got 1,238 accepted answers.

Comment: Shows wrong number of answers for myself. Thus, low confidence that the other stats are correct.

Comment: @Thomas it only counts answers for questions which have an accepted answer. Does that explain the discrepancy?

Comment: I have 168 answers, and it says 100. Seems like a bigger difference, but it's hard to say.

Comment: @Thomas just created this query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202867/answer-stats-for-thomas which confirms those figures (in a much simpler query). I guess someone else needs to confirm that the logic in the 2nd select is sound.